# How to fetch the 13th and the second last line from the standard output

Tags: linux, bash, output, line

I have a script that outputs messages to the standard output.
Now I need to fetch the 13th line from the beginning, and the second last line from this output.

I was wondering if this could be done via a single command rather than redirecting the output to the file and then reading through it few times to pull my output.

```
line 1
line 2
...
line 12
line 13
line 14
...
...
line N-1
line N
```

I need to fetch the output like:

```
line 13
line N-1
```

I have separate commands to get my lines.

To fetch the 13th line:

```
scriptoutput | head -n 13
```

To fetch the N-1 line:

```
scriptoutput | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
OR
scriptoutput | sed 'x;$!d'
```

But being standard output, I am not able to get the output done in one command.

Comment: Please do your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Added the tried commands.

Comment: Invoked with `scriptoutput | sed 'x;$!d'`, sed will process **output** of the script `scriptoutput` (so the better naming would be `script` instead of `scriptoutput`). Not sure what is a problem. See also awk-way for read the second last line: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445340/how-to-print-the-second-last-line-of-a-file-using-awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never know which line is "second to last" when reading a stream until you read the actual last line and the stream ends. The only possible way, is to always buffer the previous line, and when the stream ends, output the line from the buffer.

For example with `sed`:

```
$ seq 20 | sed -n '13p;${x;p};h'
13
19
```

etc. with similar tools.

```
seq 20 | awk 'NR==13{print} {last=current; current=$0} END{print last}'
```

```
seq 20 | { n=1; while IFS= read -r line; do if ((n++ == 13)); then printf "%s\n" "$line"; fi; previous=$current; current=$line; done && printf "%s\n" "$previous"; }
```

But you can also just buffer the whole output and count the number of lines and output the second to last line....

```
# with a file
seq 20 > tempfile ; sed -n "13p;$(( $(wc -l < tempfile) - 1 ))p" file
# with memory
seq 20 | { buf=$(cat); sed -n "13p;$(( $(wc -l <<<"$buf") - 1 ))p" <<<"$buf"; }
```

Comment: Thank you KamilCuk. The sed command is exactly what i was looking for. I did not realize that i would be able to pull both lines in the same sed command. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only(since I don't have OP's like command so I used `cat Input_file` here for testing purposes).

```
your_command | tee >(awk 'FNR==13' >&2) | tail -2 | head -1
```

Taken reference from link https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560102/188342 and in case your output is huge then you could put a sleep for(few seconds may be depending upon your output) before `tail` command here too.

Comment: Thank you. But you missed the problem I have. I do not have the text in a file. Do you mean that I will have to first same my standard output in a text file and then run your command?

Comment: @pradipti, yes, programs reading input from Input_file here. Well if you take that command's output into a output file it will be easier trust me but let me try to add another solution also here.

Comment: Thank you RavinderSingh13. But it seems this only works with cat command. Tried with standard output and got an error.
```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `tee >(awk 'FNR==13' >&2) | tail -2 | head -1'
```

Comment: @pradipti, Ok, I created one script(test one to print contents of a file) and ran it like `./script.ksh | tee >(awk 'FNR==13' >&2) | tail -2 | head -1` and it worked fine for me. How you are running program? is it a script giving output? Is it huge if not then we can do process substitution too like `awk 'FNR==NR{if(FNR==13){print};count++;next} FNR==(count-1)' <(your_script) <(your_script)` too but I didn't suggest it, try this one also once?